# eb-cli define docker-compose file when uploading complete source code to elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, continuous-deployment

is there a way to define a docker-compose file with a different name than `docker-compose.yml` when deploying a docker application (with full source code) to elastic beanstalk with eb-cli?

Details:

We are currently deploying the test stage of an application to elastic beanstalk by using the eb-cli. This is working without any problem as long as we provide a `docker-compose.yml`. In that case elastic beanstalk gets the complete source code and builds the images during the deployment. However, since the CI/CD Pipeline of our production stage is also using the `docker-compose.yml`, we need to rename the file to `docker-compose.test.yml`. Is there a way to upload the complete source code AND define a docker-compose file when using the eb-cli?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Amazon Linux 2, you can use the [prebuild hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) to rename your docker compose file:

```
# .platform/hooks/prebuild/docker_compose_cp.sh 

#!/bin/bash

cp docker-compose.test.yml docker-compose.yml
```

You should see output in the `eb-engine.log` during deployment indicating that the script has run:

```
[INFO] Executing platform hooks in .platform/hooks/prebuild/
[INFO] Following scripts will be executed in order: [docker_compose_cp.sh]
```